# How do I output the index of elements in an array that are also in another?

Tags: ruby, arrays, indexing, match

I have two arrays:

```
A = ["a","s","p","e","n"]
V = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
```

I want to output an array that shows the index of every element in array `A` that is also an element anywhere in `V`.

In other words:

```
some_function(A, V) == [0,3]
```

This is because `A[0]="a"` and `A[3]="e"` matches the elements `"a"` and `"e"` in array `V`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do:

```
A = ["a","s","p","e","n"]
V = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
A.each_index.select{|i| V.include? A[i]} # => [0, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

If V is a Set of data (order doesn't matter, no duplicates), and it is large, then you might get a performance benefit by converting it to a Set so that the `include?` runs faster since Set is built on a hash and gets O(1) retrieval time:

```
require 'set'
A = ["a","s","p","e","n"]
V = Set.new ["a","e","i","o","u"]
A.each_index.select{|i| V.include? A[i]} # => [0, 3]
```

Comment: Or just turn it into a hash and not care what the values for the pairs are, which is basically what Set does.

Answer (score 1):

As @Arup has answered your question, I thought I might elaborate a bit.  Arup suggested you do this:

```
A.each_index.select{|i| V.include? A[i]}
```

where

```
A = ["a","s","p","e","n"]
V = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
```

Firstly, what is `A.each_index`?  Try it in IRB:

```
e = A.each_index # =>  #<Enumerator: ["a", "s", "p", "e", "n"]:each_index>
e.class          # => Enumerator
e.to_a           # => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

So the enumerator `e` is the receiver of the method [Enumerable#select](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select), `Enumerable` being a mix-in module that is included by several Ruby classes, including `Enumerator`.  Want to check that?

```
e.respond_to?(:select) # => true
e.respond_to?(:map)    # => true
e.respond_to?(:reduce) # => true
```

Next, note that `A.each_index` does not depend on the contents of `A`, just its size, so we could replace that with any enumerator that iterates from 0 to `A.size - 1`, such as:

```
m = A.size
m.times.select{|i| V.include? A[i]}         # => [0, 3]
0.upto(m-1).select{|i| V.include? A[i]}     # => [0, 3]
```

We can confirm these are Enumerator objects:

```
m.times.class      # => Enumerator
0.upto(m-1).class  # => Enumerator
```

The other main classes that `include Enumerable` are `Array`, `Hash`, `Set`, `Range` and `IO` (but, since Ruby 1.9, not `String`), so we could also do this:

```
Array(0...m).select{|i| V.include? A[i]}    # => [0, 3]
(0...m).select{|i| V.include? A[i]}         # => [0, 3]
require 'set'
Set.new(0..m-1).select{|i| V.include? A[i]} # => [0, 3]
```

Note that, regardless of the receiver's class, `select` returns an array.  Most (but not all) Enumerable methods that return a collection, return an array, regardless of the receiver's class.